# do I have to create a new object or can I use a method param?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, methods, casting

So let's say I have this method that responds to a button event

```
- (void) myMethod: (id) sender
```

Is it better to use directly the function param?

```
NSLog(@"The sender tag is %d",sender.tag);
```

Or is it better to create a new object?

```
UIButton* myButton = (UIButton*) sender;
NSLog(@"The sender tag is %d",myButton.tag);
```

Why?

I've seen in tutorials that the preferred way in objective-c is the second one. But, in cases where you don't need to know the type of the sender and just access its properties/methods it should be Ok to use the first way. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is a matter of style and avoiding warnings.

Comment: You aren't "creating a new object" in any of the code above.  `UIButton* myButton = (UIButton*) sender;` merely copies the address held in `sender` to `myButton`.  The cast isn't even necessary (unless you have certain esoteric compiler warnings set to cranky pants).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not missing anything and this isn't a particularly important issue. You have a few options:

```
NSLog(@"%d", sender.tag);
```

Sometimes that will produce warnings when compiling, depending on the type of the method parameter.

```
NSLog(@"%d", ((UIButton *)sender).tag);
```

Or finally:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
NSLog(@"%d", button.tag);
```

(These all basically do the same thing, so it's mostly a matter of preference.)

Comment: So in terms of memory management it's exactly the same, right?

Comment: Yes, none of this code does anything in terms of memory management. Remember that when you do `UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender` you're just assigning pointer values.

Comment: In fact, when you compile the code (especially with optimization turned on, but perhaps even without), you're likely to get the exact same result from the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

When you say `UIButton* myButton = (UIButton*) sender;`, you are not making a new object. You are simply making a new handle (pointer) to the `sender` object, and explicitly telling the compiler that it is a `UIButton`.

This means that you can call `UIButton` methods on it without having the compiler complain that they might not exist.

From a memory point of view, you should assume it makes no difference at all. The compiler is probably smart enough to not make you a new pointer anyway, and even if it did, it's going to be 4 bytes or so, which is not worth worrying about.

Answer (score 1):

If the sender is always UIButton, I would declare method as

```
- (void) myMethod: (UIButton*) sender
```

because it practically yield the same effect to pointer type casting. It also saves you one line of code.

Comment: +1 but I usually declare the highest class in the inheritance hierarchy that defined the tag property, which without doing anything resembling research... Is UIControl